# Android: Creating Image and video Slideshow

Tags: android, video, slideshow

I am looking for a solution to create a slider show in android. I want to mix the video and image with it. I only found how to create a image only slider show.

basically, I'm using the ViewPager(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). I found lots sample for image slider. I want to know if there is a way the add video to it or third part plug-in? 
thanks

Comment: Hi @John Zhang, I want to ask if you found a solution for this issue, please I need some help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the slide show shouldn't matter.

If it is a slide show you should be able to add pictures and images to it. The only difference is that you would have different attributes for different media types.

Try suing the slide show you have found, and add video to it as if it was a picture. You'll see how it works then.

For future reference first tell us what you have tried already and share some of the code you have already written so we can let you know or guide your to the right path.